# Shadow is not visible with View() and List()

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, shadow

I have used a `View` having some buttons and a drop shadow and a followed by List
Problem is Shadow is not visible with list but visible with ScrollView.

Here is my code snap:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 1")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                Divider()
                    .frame(height: 44)
                
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 2")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .background(Color.white
                .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                .mask(Rectangle().padding(.bottom, -20))
            )

            List(0..<10) { index in
                Text("Scrollable list")
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

I have to make spacing 0 so the no space will be visbile when list is scrolling

I want to achieve View Shadow with List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because unlike `Text`s in a `ScrollView`, the list rows are opaque - they have a non-transparent background.

If you try to scroll up even further when you are already at the top of the list, you'll see the shadow is "behind" the list.

This can be fixed by setting the [`zIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/zindex(_:)) of the list, so it is behind the shadow.

```
List(0..<10) { index in
    Text("Scrollable list")
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
.zIndex(-1) // or another number that is smaller than the zIndex of the shadow
```

Also, list row backgrounds can be set by the modifier [`listRowBackground`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/listrowbackground(_:)), so you just need to do:

```
List(0..<10) { index in
    Text("Scrollable list")
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
}
```

Of course, there is also the approach of manually moving the list downwards a bit by adding `.padding(.top, someLength)`. This would be appropriate if you don't want the shadow to *cover* the first displayed row.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but in my case I have to keep the background of List and second if I give top padding or spacing between items, the space will be visible while scrolling between the item. if you have any other were out please suggest.

Comment: @VikashKumarChaubey See the edit. I apparently did not think of `zIndex` yesterday.